# MongoDB Insert a Guid, See a Guid, Filter on a Guid

Tags: c#, mongodb, uuid, .net-6.0, guid

I am just learning MongoDB and much of it I like. Until I came across this issue of storing Guids.  What seems like a simple thing is becoming quite difficult.  I've read over the GuidRepresentation portion and see that the Standard way is to store it as a binary subtype 4 (`Binary('iWoBDYb9IEOJZL4XKf1JDw==', 3)`).  I really just want to be able to insert the Guid, view the Guid in Compass and shell, and be able to filter on the Guid.  Is this possible to do while being efficient?

I have a simple User class for PoC with properties:

```
public Guid? ExternalId { get; set; }
public String Name { get; set; }
public String? Address { get; set; }
public Int32? Age { get; set; }
public String? HairColor { get; set; }
```

On creation, I do:

```
user.ExternalId = Guid.NewGuid();
var dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("testDb");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users", _mongoCollectionSettings);
var bsonDocument = model.ToBsonDocument();
await collection.InsertOneAsync(bsonDocument);
```

In Program.cs:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
```

It inserts everything perfectly fine except in MongoDB Compass and shell, the ExternalId shows up as `Binary('iWoBDYb9IEOJZL4XKf1JDw==', 3)`.  It is very important and useful, especially for debugging, to actually be able to see the actual Guid value in Compass and without copying the binary value into a console app to convert it.

Comment: I didn't get a question

Comment: Can you post some code as an example? For instance your model?

Comment: Added my PoC code for a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the following gives a warning message stating:

> 'BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode' is obsolete: 'This property will
> be removed in a later release.'

You do need to add:

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;
```

(in my case to Program.cs) as per the documentation. (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/bson/guidserialization/guidrepresentationmode/guidrepresentationmode/)  I can now view the Guid `UUID('976817aa-25f7-46e0-979d-2240a39e699f')` in MongoDB Compass.

Comment: the whole question is about what internal guid representation used or in other words which guid subType. By default, driver converts all guids to guid representation with subType 3 which is default. This behavior is called GuidRepresentationMode.V2. GuidRepresentationMode.V3 works differently. In your case it allows configuring global guid representation mode via `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer`.